# Encrypted payment form using Paypal Standard for Shopping Carts

Tags: php, forms, magento, encryption, paypal

I am trying to setup a Magento to use Paypal Standard for Shopping Carts. 
Everything seems fine using the unencrypted form but I need to encrypt the “encrypted” form variable that I am sending to PayPal. When I am sending the form to Paypal I’m getting the following error: “PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem.”.

I was trying to use the code from this website http://blog.scrobbld.com/paypal/protecting-your-payments-with-ewp/ but that seems to apply just for Paypal buttons.

Is there any way I can encrypt the request sent to Paypal using PayPal Standard?

Again, I want to use Paypal Standard for Shopping Carts as described here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA and not the Paypal button.

Comment: Look at the PayPal reference implementation for PHP. See if you missed anything.